# Velocity-time graph

Tags: kinematics

A car travelling at a constant velocity of $20m/s$ passes a stationary sport car. **Ten seconds afterwards** the sport car accelerates uniformly at $3m/s²$ to reach a speed of $30m/s$ with which it continues. Find when and where the sport car overtakes the first car.

How to indicate the bolded on a velocity time graph is the problem I'm having and hence finding a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. First of all recall the main equations of  [one-dimensional kinematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_motion#Equations_of_kinematics).

Let $v_c(t)$ and $v_s(t)$ be the velocity at time $t$ of the car and the sport car respectively. At time $t=0$, the travelling car passes the stationary sport car at the origin. Then for $t\geq 0$,
$$v_c(t)=20\quad\text{and}\quad v_s(t)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{for $t\leq 10$,}\\
3(t-10)&\text{for $10<t\leq t_1$,}\\
30&\text{for $t_1<t$.}
\end{cases}$$
where $t_1$ is a time to be found.
Can you take it from here?

Comment: @Orestes Dante Any progress? Are you still interested in solving your problem?